# MQTT - keepAlive using Arduino

Tags: mqtt, arduino

I'm using MQTT broker for my IOT devicess, mostly ESP8266 ( some are NodeMCU, some Wemos mini, and some are Sonoff) , running an Arduino code, some time ( about a year ). MQTT broker is running on a RasppberryPi Zero W, flawlessly.

All devices using my own created library, including wifi connectivty and MQTT with fucntions designed for my IOT's.

Some devices (2 or 3 of out 20)  - keep getting to `offline` state using `keepAlive` feature in MQTT ( `PubSub` library to be correct ), after 30 seconds defined. The second `Availabiliy` state goes to `offline` it updates back to `online`.

Now I'm trying to figure out the reason for it for some time, and this is the reason I decided to share:

1. As said, code is mostly generic, and my wifi+mqtt is the same for all.
2. If it was something to do with bad wifi signal causing MQTT lose connection to server, it should have initiate a `reset` command using a watch dog timer for such cases ( 20 secs to reset ).
3. I tried to change MQTT broker for that specific IOT to be sure it has nothing to da with the broker... and problem still persists.

My questions are :

1. if `#define MQTT_KEEPALIVE 30` as defined in `PubSub.h` - check only once  every 30 sec or there is more than 1 check in that time interval ??
2. Is there another way to check why or what might be the reason for an iot device losing connection with broker, getting to `keepAlive` phase, and go right back after send that lastwill ?

Answer (score 4):

The keepalive value is sent to the broker as part of the connection request. The broker uses this value to start a timer with that value that starts counting down.

Every time the client sends a packet to the broker it resets the timer. This includes publishes, responses to high QOS messages sent to the client, requests to subscribe/unsubscribe to topics.

If the timer expires (at 30s) then the broker will send the client a PINGREQ packet, to which the client should reply with a PINGREP packet, and hence resets the timer.

If the timer runs out and the broker doesn't receive a PINGREP packet from the client the broker will wait until another 0.5 * the keepalive time (15 seconds from the PINGREQ in this case) has passed before publishing any LWT for the client and marking it as disconnected. None of the keepalive handling (apart from responding to a PINGREQ) is handled by the client.

So if the client crashes 5 seconds before the PINGREQ is sent, then the watchdog will reset the device just after the LWT is published by the broker and it will reconnect (and show as online) again nearly straight away.

Comment: Let's say that client was idle during that 30s - does the broker try only once after 30s ? what does it try to do during the next 50% before sending LWT?

Comment: by the way- client never crashed in during that "behaviour"

Comment: Nothing, it waits for the response from the client

Comment: OK - but since i use `QoS = 0`, once `PINGREQ` was sent, and client didn't receive that message, it would never send a `PINGREP`..... correct ?

Comment: QOS has nothing to do keepalive/PINGREQ/PINGREP. The PINGREQ will always get to the client as it's TCP, assuming the TCP/IP stack on the device is working.

Comment: But it is sent once and if at exact time client misses `PINGREQ`  ? client would miss it and won;t send an answer.... ( is that correct ? ). BTW, during the MQTT loop it constantly tries to reconnect every `loop()` - during that time, `mqtt.connected()` replies as it is connected or not? during that 30s all tries have failed ?

Comment: The client can't miss it, it should sit on the devices TCP/IP stack until the MQTT client loop function is called. Now if you are blocking and not calling that `loop` function for more than 1/2 the keepalive time and it blocks right at the end of the 30seconds then you have a problem.

Comment: Ok. Loop is called every 100 milliseconds. So from what I understand is that the device is actually not connected the entire 30s, and all loops are ended with fails ??

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and while I expected the broker to behave as [hardillb](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/4685/10055) describes in their answer, I would still get timeouts.  To work around it, I ended up sending an MQTT ping from the client at an interval that was slightly less than the timeout period.  This solved the problem, but it seems inefficient to me.

I was not able to sniff the network traffic at the time, so I'm not sure if the broker was not sending the PINGREQ packets or if the client connection was not responding properly with a PINGREP.

Comment: Can you describe what is MQTT ping? Just an ordinary message ? I’m afraid it will cause a major traffic load for the broker.

Comment: It's just a PINGREQ from the client to the broker (1 byte - 0xC0), which forces the broker to reset its keepalive timer.  I was using Micropython on an ESP8266 using the [umqtt.simple](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/umqtt.simple/umqtt/simple.py) library and calling MQTTClient.ping at an interval that was at 90% of the keepalive time.  TBH there may very well have been a misunderstanding of how to properly use the MQTT library on my part, but this fixed the problem in my app and the LWT functioned as you would expect when the client truly went offline.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in :

void loop use client.loop();

Had the same issue mosquitto disconect the wifi was still working ,
i saw in the mosquitto log the disconnect due to timeout exceeded and after the loop it keeped working.

The loop in the Arduino/esp32 is so busy that the keep alive wil not work from the mqtt lib.

hope that this helps some people.